# 80s-90s comic where Punisher's van gets blown up... twice

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, the-punisher

This happened probably sometime in the late eighties to mid-nineties, when Microchip was Frank's regular partner.  Frank had his Battle Van, equipped with a lot of expensive technology.  It got blown up several times, and cost a ton of money to replace.

I remember one comic where the van got blown up.  Micro needs something like  $100,000 to make a downpayment on a replacement.

In the next story the van gets blown up again. A furious Micro rants that they got less than 100 miles on the clock.

Which issues did this happen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Punisher* #28 (1989) and #29 (1990), part of the "Acts of Vengeance" storyline featuring the Kingpin and Victor Von Doom as villains.

In issue #28, it's Frank (not Microchip) who talks about several vans getting trashed, about a million dollars a piece:

[image: Frank Castle uses an ejectable seat while destroying a Battle Can and getting irked at the cost]

In issue #29, Doom messes up the electricals on the new van, and this time it *is* Microchip who complains about the cost, especially considering the current van's young age:

[image: Microchip complains about having to replace the electricals on a 124-miles-old van]

---

Found by browsing [the Battle Van's page on the Marvel Wikia](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Punisher%27s_Battle_Van/Appearances), looking at 90s issues where the van would appear in two or three issues in a row (since the question mentioned it being thrashed over one issue and the next).

Comment: That's the one, thanks.